# How to approach compound verbs?

Tags: compounds

I'm at a point where I keep encountering new compound verbs and I'm not sure how I should approach them to study. Is there a list or category of "main" compound suffixes (like 続ける, 始める, etc.) that carries the same meaning for every compound? What are the rules for making compound verbs (if there are any)?

Comment: Sometimes verbs might look compound but are more a matter of one thing happens and then the other, and the speaker / writer is omitting the ～て.  Do you have any examples that you could share?

Comment: How to approach them?  Slowly and quietly; don't scare them.

Comment: @istrasci I think there's an English verb for what you describe: "creep".

Comment: @EddieKal: Yeah, but there's a 15-character minimum limit on comments, so I had to expound on it.

Comment: I guess English phrasal verbs are _far_ more unpredictable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of compound verbs: *syntactic* and *lexical*.

According to [Compound Verb Lexicon](https://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/en/), there are 30 syntactic compound verbs in Japanese. You can find the full list in the link (Click "Syntactic and Lexical Compound Verbs" on the left pane). 続ける and 始める belong to this category, so their meanings are straightforward regardless of what comes as the first verb. The meanings of most syntactic compound verbs are related to starting, ending, continuing, repeating, etc.

On the other hand, there are also thousands of lexical compound verbs, and it takes time to master them. They are called *lexical* because they are unpredictable and there is no clear rule (although there are weak tendencies which you can gradually notice). Basically you have to remember each combination one by one.